# Copyleaks SDK Java Examples

Tags: copyleaks-api

I have gone through the API docs for CopyLeaks and I understand the API urls listed.

However, since the SDK libraries are listed on the site, i think it may make the process of integration more easier.

However can you help me find examples of Java code illustrating usage of  Copy leaks SDK?

Answer (score 1):

How to use the Copyleaks Java SDK - [example](https://github.com/Copyleaks/Java-Plagiarism-Checker/blob/master/src/main/java/example/Example.java).